# Laravel 5 route using server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I installed Laravel 5 on a ftp server. Everything is fine, the main page is enable. But I have a problem with my routes. A link is calling a route which is calling a controller which is returning a view.

My link :

```
<div class="logo"><a href="{{ route('accueil') }}"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
```

My route :

```
Route::get('/', [
'as' => 'accueil',
'uses' => 'ControllerTest@accueil']);
```

My controller :

```
class ControllerTest extends Controller
{
    public function accueil()
    {
        return view('accueil');
    }

}
```

But when I look to my element, I can see this : href="http://XX.XXX.XX.XXXC:/test/public/index.php" instead of href="http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/test/public/index.php"

It seems like Laravel is mixing the server's IP and the localhost. I can't find what's wrong. I searched online a solution, but I always have this issue.

There is my .htaccess file in /public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

And there is my httpd.conf file used by apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot C:/htdocs
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions Inherit 
  <Directory "C:/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And, I have enable the rewrite_module in the same file (httpd.conf) like this :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I don't understand why it can't work. If someone has an idea to help me.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Surely it should be `c:\ ` rather than `c:/` in your httpd conf?

Comment: I changed it in my file. Then, I restarted my Apache and I still have the same issue : href="http://XX.XXX.XX.XXXC:/test/public/index.php"